# How to GRAB a variable from UI thread while in a working thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, http, dispatcher

I'm making slow progress on a simple application I'm making: it creates a request, fills out the headers and fetches a webpage for me. I figured out that in order to update the UI (after a button has been pressed) I must use dispatcher like so:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, new delegate_onearg_s(UpdateStatus), "Sending Request...");
```

In this case I have an UpdateStatus(string message) which sets my label_Status = message;

So far so good. Now I want it to take input from a textbox first and then turn it into a URL that is used later to create the request, but how do I do that? I've tried this:

```
string url = Convert.ToString(Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, new delegate_string_get(GetInput)));
```

GetInput() in this case simply does return textBox.Text; 
That doesn't really work - it returns some generic thing that's related to the dispatcher.

How can I get a variable from a textbox in the UI thread and get it in the working thread with the dispatcher?

Merci beacoup :)

PS. There's a very high probability I don't know what I'm doing. Just keep that in mind when answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need to use `Invoke`, not `BeginInvoke`. `BeginInvoke` executes the delegate asynchronously on the dispatcher thread, but you need to get the result synchronously.

```
string url = (string)Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<string>(GetInput));
```

Answer (score 0):

before starting the thread, declare a string variable and assign to it the value from textBox then use that variable in your GetInput method.

```
string myVal = myTextBox.Text;
```

...
   use it in your GetInput.

Comment: If all the fields are empty when the application starts and the work is done when the button is pressed, then the string needs to be assigned the value after the button is pressed, and not before, am I wrong? And so in that scenario, I really can't do anything with the string until I press the button in which case I'm tied up in the thread that's created by the button being pressed.